# How can i test this url in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Hi friends i'm trying to test this urls but i don't how do that, i have the following code but it doesn't work

```
# Method of the test
def testViewDeleteUserIsResolved(self):
        url = reverse('inventory:viewDeleteUser', args={'idUser': tbUser.objects.first().id})
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func,viewDeleteUser)

# Url to try
path('viewDeleteUser/?P<idUser>[0-9a-f-]+', views.viewDeleteUser, name='viewDeleteUser'),
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `reverse('inventory:viewDeleteUser')` stands for. I am also a newbie to Django, but I think it will work if you change it to `reverse('viewDeleteUser')`.

`tests.py`

```py
from django.urls import reverse
from .views import viewDeleteUser
def testViewDeleteUserIsResolved(self):
        url = reverse('viewDeleteUser', args={'idUser': tbUser.objects.first().id})
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func,viewDeleteUser)
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('viewDeleteUser/?P<idUser>[0-9a-f-]+', views.viewDeleteUser, name='viewDeleteUser'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Django app you have to create a url.py file where all your urls live, you have to put that path() instruction you have in that file.

Then your function needs to be in the views.py file, also take in count the name of the function has to be the same you're declaring in the path() as far I see you you're using views.viewDeleteUser so in the views.py file you need a function like this:

```html
def viewDeleteUser:
```